# Configuring separate development and production sites on the same server  (IIS)

Tags: iis, coldfusion

I have a IIS/ColdFusion question. I am working with a client, who has both production and development stuff on the same machine. He has two drives, C and E. C drive has development files and E drive has production. The IIS configuration points to E drive. C drive the has the following structure:

```
C:/ 
   - Coldfusion 9 
   - Inetpub    
     - coldfusion files 

 E:/ 
   - Web     
     - coldfusion files
```

But Iam confused if IIS can point to two different drives? How to find out which drive the IIS point out to.. I hope I am not vague with my question

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I would advise against doing development work on the same server as production.  Bad code can hang the server, or slow it down to the point that it's not useful for the public.  Develop on a local box.  If possible, test your code on a machine set up as much like the production server as possible.

Comment: To expand on what @Ben Doom is saying, you should have three servers, development, staging and production.  I usually keep my development server on my local machine in a VM.  The staging server is the one that should be identical (or as close to it as possible) to your production box.  Generally smaller companies will combine the production and staging boxes into a similar configuration to yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IIS you will need to create new web sites.

Configure each site to respond to either a different IP address or a different host header and point each site at the different folders.